# Facebook Graph API - Object Insights for any Photo returns 0 for all Metrics

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, photo

Using the Facebook Graph API I am able to retrieve data for a photo post - I can see the object likes and object comments which return data. So I know I have the correct ID for the photo.

However when I try to use object insights all the values returned are 0, which I know is not true via the insights dashboard on my account: https://www.facebook.com/{page name}/insights/

The query I am running is:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/{page id}_{post id}/insights
```

Which I am doing via the API tool: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer

If I try a status or a link, they return values.

Does anybody have any ideas?

Comment: How did you get the post ID? did you get it from `GET /{PAGE-ID}/feed`? or construct it yourself? I have check this for one photo in a test page and some metrics returned values as expected ([here's an example](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/?session_id=836914503072326))

Comment: I was using the image object id and not the actual post id - I have now figured out where to get that. Many thanks for pointing me in the right direction :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I figured this out finally...

If you query all posts /{page_id}/posts and find the post you are after, at the very top is the following:

```
{
      "id": "112665855555813_473845879437807", 
      "from": {
        "category":
```

And that is the id that you need to use and not use the object id

```
"type": "photo", 
"status_type": "added_photos", 
"object_id": "473462762809452",
```

Which is what I was doing. This is a different number and is the one you will get if you view the post on facebook - its the id of the photo and not the actual post.